# Docker volumes mounting on Windows 8 is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

## Context

I want to run a Docker Compose application on a Windows 8. I made it under a Ubuntu 16.04 and it's perfectly working on it.

This Docker Compose run:

- nginx
- php-fpm

The two containers use volumes.

## Files

My `.env` file:

```
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
APPLICATION_PATH=//C/Users/my_user/Documents/Development/my_application
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: ../application-web/
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    tty: true
    # Add a volume to link php code on the host and inside the container
    volumes:
     - ${APPLICATION_PATH}:/usr/share/nginx/html/application
     - ${APPLICATION_PATH}/docker_files/docker-assistant:/usr/share/nginx/html/assistant
    # Add hostnames to allow devs to call special url to open sites
    extra_hosts:
     - "localhost:127.0.0.1"
     - "assistant.docker:127.0.0.1"
     - "application.dev:127.0.0.1"
    depends_on:
     - custom-php
    links:
     - custom-php:custom-php

  custom-php:
    build: ../application-php/
    ports:
     - "50:50"
    volumes:
     - ${APPLICATION_PATH}:/usr/share/nginx/html/application
     - ${APPLICATION_PATH}/docker_files/docker-assistant:/usr/share/nginx/html/assistant
```

## Problem

When I run `docker-compose up`, everything goes well. Containers start.
But when I try to reach http://192.168.99.100 in my web browser, I got a 403 error.

My investigations show that there is no mounted volumes in the nginx and the php containers:

```
docker exec -it compose_web_1 bash
ls -la /usr/share/nginx/html/assistant/
```

shows

```
drwxr.xr.x 2 root root   80 May 18 15:30 .
drwxr.xr.x 2 root root 4096 May 18 16:10 ..
```

It seems that Docker cannot mount volumes. Why?

## Other information

- I am using the Docker Toolbox: https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox
- I know that's the good IP address because when I try to reach it in my web browser, I see my nginx container displaying logs.
- The environment variable `APPLICATION_PATH` set as `//C:/Users/my_user/Documents/Development/my_application` cannot work because Docker use the ":" character as separator for volume declaration:

  > ERROR: Volume //C:/Users/my_user/Documents/Development/my_application://C:/Users/my_user/Documents/Development/my_application has incorrect format, should be external:internal[:mode]
- It's not a nginx problem because when I create an `index.phtml` file in the folder, I am able to run it:

  ```
  <?php
  echo 'Hello world!';
  ```

Comment: Do you use "docker for windows"? Could you verify, that the volume "C" is shared? Could you add the colon in the application path ( `APPLICATION_PATH=C:/Users/my_user/Documents/Development/my_application`). Maybe [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693) will help. Furthermore, please verify the ip address.

Comment: How can I verify that "C" is shared? For the other questions, I edited my original post.

Comment: @Holger thank to your question, I was able to find what was the problem. You can see my answer below, thank you!

Comment: And as usual, I would be very happy to know why my question is downvoted :|

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I finally did it!

## TL;DR

Follow those instructions to be able to access C:\ inside your containers.

### 1. Install the Docker Toolbox

Go get it here: https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox

Install it.

### 2. Run a Hello world

Open a Docker Quickstart Terminal.

[image: Docker Quickstart Terminal opened]

Run in it:

```
docker run hello-world
```

### 3. Share C:\ with Docker

Open Virtualbox

[image: Virtualbox opened]

Open configuration of the `default` virtual machine and go to `shared folders`

[image: Configuration of the default virtual machine]

Modify or create a new shared folder by clicking on buttons to the right. Set options to:

- `C:\`
- `C`
- Auto mount
- Permanent configuration

Then validate.

[image]

### 4. Activate sharing

Shutdown the `default` virtual machine then restart it.

### 5. Set your paths

e.G. if you have a `.env` file:

```
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
APPLICATION_PATH=//C/path_from_C_to_the_folder_you_want_to_share_on_the_volume
```

**/!\** *you* **need** *to set `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` to 1!*

### 6. Start your Compose

In the Docker Quickstart Terminal:

[image: Docker Quickstart Terminal opened]

Go to your Docker Compose folder, then start it:

```
cd /path_to_your_compose_folder
docker-compose up
```

---

## Why have I to do that? It's so complicated!

The Docker technology rely on Linux namespaces. Without Linux, it can't work. To allow use of Docker on a Windows, Docker needs to install a Linux virtual machine. All the containers will run inside it.

[image: Docker stack explained]

The `default` virtual machine is now created and running within Virtualbox, that's why you have to share your folders using Virtualbox.

After sharing, the `default` virtual machine will have a mounted folder in it with a custom name (in the above example, it's `C` but it could be `elephant` or whatever).

Finally, Docker will mount volumes from the `default` virtual machine to the container: you have to use the name of the `default` machine shared folder in your volume declaration (in the above example, it's `C` but it could be `elephant` or whatever).

[image: Docker folder share explained]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I was struggling with this for quite a while and thanks to your post I solved this.