# docker-compose volumes are not mounting properly

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

I have the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: chatt-friends-api
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/appDev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    env_file: docker/web-Dockerfile.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/web-Dockerfile.yml
```

with the following directory structure

[image]

Now when I run docker-compose up and move into the chatt-friends-api container and navigate into the appDev folder.  I see two folders inside which are docker, and node_modules.  I have no idea why this is so.  For your reference this is what web-Dockerfile.yml looks like.  I'm copying the whole src folder here anyway, but was trying to see if the volumes get mounted properly as well.

```
from node:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post the answer here in case someone else has the problem.  I was primarily using VirtualBox on Windows 8 and this has to do with shared folders.  You need to share a folder and map it to a version unix understands.

The answer is explained here quite well

[Docker volumes mounting on Windows 8 is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054058/docker-volumes-mounting-on-windows-8-is-not-working)